# What does it mean when a class is not PAC learnable?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, pac-learning

I understood that when a hypothesis class is PAC learnable, we can learn about the sample size, accuracy, and confidence.
Suppose we have following problem which is not PAC learnable:

Input: $\{0,1\}^n$

Output: $\{0,1\}$

Complexity: $m ≥ \frac{1}{\varepsilon} (2^n\log 2 + \log\frac{1}{\delta})$

What can we say about it and its learnability? Is there any way to find proper $m$ to have high accuracy?